# Are there attacks which are specific to Linux?

Tags: linux, attacks

I am currently studying cyber security and we were asked what are some specific methods to gain unauthorized access of a Linux system. On my search on the internet, I keep seeing various intrusion methods. I was thinking SQL injection, XML, PL/SQL, but I don’t know if those are specific to Windows. Any clarification will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea that your actual question is. Can you try and rephrase this? Also, read [ask].

Comment: I just want to know what are some of the methods in which an intruder can use to gain unauthorized access to a system running Linux. That is, what vulnerabilities in linux can make the system subject to exploitation

Comment: That question is way too broad. There are decades of vulnerabilities that allow that.

Comment: @Nadege: if you understand what these attacks do and if you understand what software can run on a Linux system then you will be able to answer your question yourself. Example: SQL  injection needs an SQL database. Are such databases available on Linux? If yes, then the attack is relevant there. But in the current form your question looks more like you've heard some buzzwords somewhere and just posted these here without an understanding of what these things actually mean.

Comment: I understand your response. I just wanted to know what classes or types of vulnerabilities have been noted in the past which were specific to Linux  is what I’m really asking

Comment: @Nadege: I've edited your question based on your last comment to make more clear what you are asking. Attacks specific to Linux are mostly attacks which rely on [vulnerabilities of the Linux kernel](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/47/Linux-Linux-Kernel.html). At the user space you'll find mostly attacks which are relevant on other UNIX like systems too or even on Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The attacks you talk about are on services which might be running on mswindows, linux, bsd, vms, os9, qnx...any operating system.

You seem to be confused as to the nature of a kernel (such as linux) an operating system and a configured machine. Although linux is a kernel, the term is commonly (although incorrectly) is applied to operating systems. Indeed linux usually comes bundled with a lot of applcations/servers.

If you are really only interested in kernel related vulnerabilities, then  you should be focussing your research on tcp/ip vulnerabilities and privilege escalation attacks.